# Putting together Powershell script to document SQL Server with Instances

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Ok, this is a messy one, so bear with me.

We have a PowerShell script that runs from our CMS/Master SQL Managment Server that fetches information from all servers we have, specified in a one column table (`[SQLServerInformation].[dbo].[server_list]`). The script will then go through the list with a `foreach` loop and query the servers and write whatever information it receives back into another table in the same database (`[SQLServerInformaton].[dbo].[$ServerName_server_trunc]`, so the table name will be whatever server was just queried in the loop. E.g. `[sqlserver01_server_trunc]` or `[managementsql11_server_trunc]`).

The issue I'm having is that I'm also trying to extract what instances are running on the server. The instances will always run with the same SQL Server version, so I don't need any advanced script that will go through the registry (which I've read is not a good idea). The script (which works completely fine without the instance related bits) I've created so far is this:

```
# We store all SQL Servers in this table. Here we fetch them into a variable.
$QueryFetchServerNames = "SELECT ServerName AS Name FROM [SQLServerInformation].[dbo].[server_list]"

# Make sure we don't run into the "System.Data.DataRow" problem.
$ServerName = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance CBSWSQLMGT01 -Query $QueryFetchServerNames).Name

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {
    # Fetch the instances under the server.
    $Instances = Get-ChildItem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$Server"

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Query "
        SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [Server], 
        "$Instances | foreach-object { $_ }" AS [Instance(s)],
           (SELECT Server_type = CASE 
                                   WHEN virtual_machine_type = 1 THEN 'Virtual' 
                                   ELSE 'Physical' 
                                 END 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [Virtual/Physical], 
           (SELECT ( cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio ) 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [CPU(s)], 
           (SELECT CASE 
                     WHEN hyperthread_ratio = cpu_count THEN cpu_count 
                     WHEN ( ( cpu_count - hyperthread_ratio ) / ( 
                            cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio ) ) 
                          = 0 THEN 1 
                   END 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [Core(s)], 
           (SELECT ( [total_physical_memory_kb] / 1024 ) AS [RAM (MB)] 
            FROM   [master].[sys].[dm_os_sys_memory]) AS [RAM (MB)], 
           LEFT(@@VERSION, Charindex(')', @@VERSION)) AS [Version], 
           SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS [Build], 
           SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS [Edition];"| 

           # Write it all into a table.
           Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance CBSWSQLMGT01 -DatabaseName SQLServerInformation -SchemaName dbo -TableName $ServerName_server_trunc -Force
}
```

I get the output:

```
PS D:\PowerShell\ServerInformation\cbswsqlmgt01> D:\PowerShell\ServerInformation\cbswsqlmgt01\test.ps1
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At D:\PowerShell\ServerInformation\cbswsqlmgt01\test.ps1:30 char:5
+     Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Query "
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
 
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '[CBSWSQLMGT01]'.
At D:\PowerShell\ServerInformation\cbswsqlmgt01\test.ps1:30 char:5
+     Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Query "
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

If I run just this, the instances will display fine:

```
# We store all SQL Servers in this table. Here we fetch them into a variable.
$QueryFetchServerNames = "SELECT ServerName AS Name FROM [SQLServerInformation].[dbo].[server_list]"

# Make sure we don't run into the "System.Data.DataRow" problem.
$ServerName = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance CBSWSQLMGT01 -Query $QueryFetchServerNames).Name

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {
    # Fetch the instances under the server.
    $Instances = Get-ChildItem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$Server"
    $Instances | foreach-object { $_ }
    Write-Host "--------"
}

PS D:\PowerShell\ServerInformation\cbswsqlmgt01> D:\PowerShell\ServerInformation\cbswsqlmgt01\test.ps1

Instance Name                                                                   
-------------                                                                   
ATLASSIAN                                                                       
COGNOS                                                                          
DEFAULT                                                                         
METAFORCE                                                                       
NAVISION                                                                        
PIVOTAL                                                                         
QUANTUM                                                                         
ZERVICEPOINT                                                                    
--------
DEFAULT                                                                         
--------
```

So, my question is, how can I print out the instances of the server, and at the same time, write them to the database table `[SQLServerInformation].[dbo].[$ServerName_server_trunc]`?

### Solution by [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin):

```
# We store all SQL Servers in this table. Here we fetch them into a variable.
$ServerName = (Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance CBSWSQLMGT01 -Query "SELECT ServerName AS Name FROM [SQLServerInformation].[dbo].[server_list]").Name

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {
    # Fetch the instances under the server.
    $Instances = Get-ChildItem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$Server"
    $InstanceString = ($Instances.Name -join "`r`n" | Out-String).Trim()
    $InstanceString = $InstanceString.Replace("$Server`r`n","MSSQLSERVER`r`n")
    $InstanceString = $InstanceString.Replace("$Server\","")

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance CBSWSQLMGT01 -Query "
        TRUNCATE TABLE [SQLServerInformation].[dbo].[$Server`_server]
    "

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Query "
        SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [Server], 
    '$InstanceString' AS [Instance(s)],
           (SELECT Server_type = CASE 
                                   WHEN virtual_machine_type = 1 THEN 'Virtual' 
                                   ELSE 'Physical' 
                                 END 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [Virtual/Physical], 
           (SELECT ( cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio ) 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [CPU(s)], 
           (SELECT CASE 
                     WHEN hyperthread_ratio = cpu_count THEN cpu_count 
                     WHEN ( ( cpu_count - hyperthread_ratio ) / ( 
                            cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio ) ) 
                          = 0 THEN 1 
                   END 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [Core(s)], 
           (SELECT ( [total_physical_memory_kb] / 1024 ) AS [RAM (MB)] 
            FROM   [master].[sys].[dm_os_sys_memory]) AS [RAM (MB)], 
           LEFT(@@VERSION, Charindex(')', @@VERSION)) AS [Version], 
           SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS [Build], 
           SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS [Edition];"| 

           # Write it all into a table.
           Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance CBSWSQLMGT01 -DatabaseName SQLServerInformation -SchemaName dbo -TableName $Server`_server -Force
}
```

Comment: have you looked at dbatools? This is an entire suite of PowerShell commands designed specifically for SQL Server: https://dbatools.io/

Comment: Yes, but I have yet to find anything that will print out all instances on the server.

Comment: @tobulos1 We are actually working on a `Find-DbaInstance` now, hopefully it will hit release this week. You can see code for it in the active PR [here](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/pull/3344)

Comment: To get system/OS level information you can currently use `Get-DbaComputerSystem` and/or `Get-DbaOperatingSystem` they both pull various bits of information for a given server or array of servers you pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you could tweak to your preferences.

I created a comma separated string of the instances and included that as a literal into the `invoke-sqlcmd`.  In the following example, I hardcoded my local computer name (sc-hgrckb2) which has 3 instances.

Per your comment, I used a couple of `REPLACE` functions to make the `DEFAULT` instance show up as "DEFAULT" and also removed the server name and slash from the named instances.  (In my testing, the *Default Instance* always showed up first in the $InstanceString.)

```
$ServerName = "sc-hgrckb2"

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {
    # Fetch the instances under the server.
    $Instances = Get-ChildItem -Path "SQLSERVER:\SQL\$Server"
    $InstanceString = ($Instances.Name -join "," | Out-String).Trim()
    $InstanceString = $InstanceString.Replace("$ServerName,","DEFAULT,")
    $InstanceString = $InstanceString.Replace("$ServerName\","")

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Query "
        SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [Server], 
    '''$InstanceString''' AS [Instance(s)],
           (SELECT Server_type = CASE 
                                   WHEN virtual_machine_type = 1 THEN 'Virtual' 
                                   ELSE 'Physical' 
                                 END 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [Virtual/Physical], 
           (SELECT ( cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio ) 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [CPU(s)], 
           (SELECT CASE 
                     WHEN hyperthread_ratio = cpu_count THEN cpu_count 
                     WHEN ( ( cpu_count - hyperthread_ratio ) / ( 
                            cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio ) ) 
                          = 0 THEN 1 
                   END 
            FROM   sys.dm_os_sys_info) AS [Core(s)], 
           (SELECT ( [total_physical_memory_kb] / 1024 ) AS [RAM (MB)] 
            FROM   [master].[sys].[dm_os_sys_memory]) AS [RAM (MB)], 
           LEFT(@@VERSION, Charindex(')', @@VERSION)) AS [Version], 
           SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS [Build], 
           SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS [Edition];"
}
```

The results were:

```
Server           : SC-HGRCKB2
Instance(s)      : 'DEFAULT,RESTOREENCRYPT,SQL2017'
Virtual/Physical : Physical
CPU(s)           : 1
Core(s)          : 12
RAM (MB)         : 16306
Version          : Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU3-GDR)
Build            : 14.0.3015.40
Edition          : Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit)
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I see what the problem is now. You store only one server in the variable `$ServerName`, and it works. I fetch two server names with the variable `$QueryFetchServerNames`. That's why it's not working for me, I believe.

Comment: Never mind, I just had to change `$ServerName` to `$Server` in the replace arguments! Now it works as expected. Full solved code in my description. Thank you so much for your help :)